# how to push elements to empty fixed size array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am completely newbie to java. I want to reverse an array. So I have created one new empty array with the size of input array. Now I want to push elements from input array to new array by accessing elements of input array from backside.

There might be methods to reverse the array, but I don't want to use them. I want to write the logic to reverse.

So, here my question is, is there any method to push an element to array, like `arrayOne.push(arrayTwo[index])`

```
public int rotateArray(int[] a) {    
  int[] intArray=new int[a.length];
  for(i=a.length-1;i--){
      intArray.push(a[i]) // How to push the element to array here...
  }
}
```

Before asking this question, I researched in Google and checked some already existed stackoverflow questions, but didn't help me...

Comment: Java arrays are not a stack, and they are never "empty" (because an `int[]` has a fixed length, and can only hold primitive `int`(s)) the default value is `0`.

Comment: instead of push, wouldn't it simply be intArray[i] = a[I] ?

Comment: I think you are confusing javascript with java. To push elements in the array in java, you have to use indexes to assign them. So it would be `intArray[a.length-i-1] = a[i]`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch got your point, thank you. Then how can I finish my code. Suggestions please...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare Java Array and insert data into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997121/how-to-declare-java-array-and-insert-data-into-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `Arrays` do not work as `Stack`.
To reverse, you could do something like below:

```
public int[] rotateArray(int[] a) {    
         int n = a.length;
         int[] intArray=new int[n];

         for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
                intArray[n-i] = a[i-1];
         }
         return intArray;
}
```

`Arrays` have fixed size. You can also use [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) with [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))